# SetTimeout не работает при удалении элемента

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="start"> 
      <div>текст</div>
      <a href="google.com">кнопка перехода куда-то</a>
    </div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function thrash(){
    var o=document.querySelector('a[href="google.com"]');
    o.remove();
}
setTimeout(thrash, 5000);
</script>
```

Почему-то сразу удаляет, не ожидая 5 сек..

Comment: вы вызываете функцию, которая уже вызвана при загрузке страницы

Comment: ааа, вон оно что, спасибо!))

Answer (score 0):

Запускайте таймер внутри обработчика `window.onload` :

```html
<div class="start">
  <div>текст</div>
  <a href="google.com">кнопка перехода куда-то</a>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.onload = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector('a[href="google.com"]').remove();
    }, 5000);
  }
</script>
```